# How to cast complex double in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers

I am calling C functions in a 3rd party library, which return complex numbers using a custom type:

```
typedef struct
{
  double dat[2];
} complex_num;
```

Here, dat[0] is the real part and dat[1] is the imaginary part. I want to safely and portably cast these to the C `complex double` type to use optimized math operations like add/multiply etc. Suppose I have a function returning `complex_num`:

```
complex_num dostuff(...);
```

**My question is, can I safely do the following:**

```
complex double a = (complex double) dostuff(...);
```

Are there any issues with array padding/alignments which would screw up the above cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write yourself a conversion function:

```
complex double MyCast(complex_num x) { return CMPLX(x.dat[0], x.dat[1]); }
```

`CMPLX` is a standard macro, defined in `<complex.h>`. Apple LLVM 10.0.1 with clang-1001.0.46.4 and GCC 9.1 optimize this use of `CMPLX` to no operation, at least in one scenario I tested.

Comment: I would add that `CMPLX` is C11.

Answer (score -2):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Complex_floating_types:

> Each complex type has the same object representation and alignment requirements as an array of two elements of the corresponding real type (`float` for `float complex`, `double` for `double complex`, `long double` for `long double complex`). The first element of the array holds the real part, and the second element of the array holds the imaginary component.

So, it would be perfectly valid to write it like this:

```c
complex double a;
{
    complex_num a_ = dostuff(...);
    memcpy(&a, &a_, sizeof(a));
}
```